# Load u-boot.ldr in bf548 ezkit using sd card

Tags: u-boot, bsp

i am working on **BF548 EZKIT LITE**, i had done tftp booting in it. Kernel and jffs2 file system loaded successfully and got the root prompt.

But now i need to use SD card for booting, I had made ext2 partition into sd card and copy u-boot.ldr(boot loader) in it, but when try to load this file after inserting SD card into board i had got an error like

> tranfering data failed
>   ** ext4fs_devread read error - block
>
> Failed to mount ext2 filesystem...
>
> ** Unrecognized filesystem type **

search on net but could not find anything , add log for detail which shows SD card is detected.

`bfin> mmcinfo
Device: Blackfin SDH
Manufacturer ID: 3
OEM: 5344
Name: SD02G 
Tran Speed: 25000000
Rd Block Len: 512
SD version 2.0
High Capacity: No
Capacity: 1.8 GiB
Bus Width: 4-bit
bfin>
bfin> ext2load mmc 0 0x1000000 u-boot.ldr
tranfering data failed
 ** ext4fs_devread read error - block
Failed to mount ext2 filesystem...
** Unrecognized filesystem type **
bfin>`

I had tried different sd card also but still got the same problem, Any one have clue about this? Please share.

U-boot version= 2014.07.
Linux kernel = 4.5.4

I am using Buildroot for making board support package.

Thank in advance....

Comment: On a Linux host with the SD card inserted what does 'tune2fs -l /dev/SDCARDPARTITION | grep 64bit' show?  If that feature, along with metadata_csum are set, you'll need to recreate that partition with those features disabled.

Comment: @TomRini

`sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdb1 | grep 64bit` This print nothing on terminal.



`sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdb | grep 64bit` This print below error

**tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.**

Answer (score 1):

Ah, so your problem is:

```
bfin> ext2load mmc 0 0x1000000 u-boot.ldr
```

and this should be:

```
bfin> ext4load mmc 0:1 0x1000000 u-boot.ldr
```

as you need to specify both the MMC device (0) and the partition on the device (1 as you made 1 partition on the SD card and formatted that).  Just saying 0 causes it to try and read the whole device as where the filesystem is which fails when it runs into the partition table.  And you need to use 'ext4load' (or just load, if you have the generic commands enabled) as well since you've got ext3/ext4 most likely and not just ext2.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, 

I had tried as you suggested just now, but still its showing same error.

Comment: Ah, I think I see the other problem now, updated answer.

Comment: Tried updated suggestion also but still got the same error  

`bfin>ext4load mmc 0:1 0x1000000 u-boot.ldr`  

tranfering data failed  
** ext4fs_devread read error - block  

Failed to mount ext2 filesystem...  

** Unrecognized filesystem type **